# Browser doesn't respect the decimal value of width

Tags: css

I'm creating a complex layout where I need calculate the width of displayed elements

The calculation contains some decimal values ( zooming coefficient ... )

I found that the source of problems was the browser doesn't respect the width that i did pass i'm passing a **56,50px** when i inspect the element i found the browser gived a width of **56,49px** , 
0.1 when it accumulate with 140 elements it becomes 14px of unprecision !

i know peoples talked about that before but i did not found a complete answer of how to solve this kind of issue

thanks in advance for help

[image]

[image]

Comment: u gave width of 5650px and browser interpreted it as 5649.1px? Very unclear what u want u ask? Can u create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: That's a complex matter, browsers may actually even round coordinates for rendering (to avoid anitaliasing), but still report floating numbers. The floating values reported by getBoundingClientRect or the dev tools may themselves be affected by a lot of things like other elements' padding or the scrolling of the page. I second the previous comment asking for a [mcve], solutions will vary depending on the case.

Comment: no i'm playing just with decimals i gived 50,33px and browser interpretted 50,20px also sometimes and give 40,60px and browser interpretted 40,59px

Comment: i added an image in my question